How to escape ( when I query the MS AD LDAP
Here is my code:
import ldap from 'ldapjs';
import fs from "fs";
import dotenvFlow from 'dotenv-flow';
dotenvFlow.config();
let config = {
    baseDN: ..........,
    groupDN: ........,
    url: process.env["AD_LDAP_URL"]
}
let client;
try {
    client = ldap.createClient(config);
    let opts = {
        attributes: ['distinguishedName'],
        filter: "distinguishedName=CN=post.AP(R)34," + config.groupDN,
        "scope": "sub"
    }        
    await bind(process.env["AD_USER_NAME"], process.env["AD_PASSWORD"]);

    let searchResult = await search(config.baseDN, opts);
    console.log(searchResult);    
} catch (error) {
    throw error
} finally{
    await unbind();
}

async function bind(userName, password) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.bind(userName, password, async err => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            }
            resolve();
        });
    });
}
async function search(dn, opts) {
    const entries = [];
    let referrals = [];
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.search(dn, opts, function (err, response) {
            response.on('searchEntry', function (entry) {
                entries.push(entry);
            });
            response.on('searchReference', referral => {
                referrals = referrals.concat(referral.uris);
            });
            response.on('error', error => {
                return reject(error);
            })
            response.on('end', result => {
                if (result.status !== 0) {
                    return reject(result.status);
                }

                return resolve({
                    entries: entries,
                    referrals: referrals
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
async function unbind() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.unbind(err => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve();
        });
    });
}

It prompts the "Error: unbalanced parentheses".
When I change the following:
filter: "distinguishedName=CN=(R)," + config.groupDN,

to
filter: "distinguishedName=CN=\(R," + config.groupDN,

The error message is gone.
However when I change the above to
filter: "distinguishedName=CN=\(R\)," + config.groupDN,

The error message came back.
So, how can I escape the right parentheses?
My environment as the below:
node.js version 22
"ldapjs": "^3.0.7"
My LDAP server is an MS AD DC.
The actual content of filter as below:
filter: 'distinguishedName=CN=post.AP(R)34,OU=Group Objects,DC=ad,DC=abc'


I think that to answer this, the contents of config.groupDN are highly required... When it says "unbalanced parentheses" it means (in my humble opinion) that there's a missing parentheses (opening or closing parentheses) or even that it is misplaced (ex.: 1 + ( 2 - [ 3 + 4 ) * 5 ]).

Question text is updated.

Try
Any occurrence of the open parenthesis character must be escaped as “\28”.
Any occurrence of the close parenthesis character must be escaped as “\29”.
